# Javascript setInterval not making it into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok Im trying to do a setInterval into a sub function and its not making it in there...my alert is not firing off because of this:

```
var doneVar= 0;
var groupsVar= 4;
var interval = setInterval(process_chunk, 1000);
var $myTree= $("#myTree");
var chunkLength = myArray.length / groupsVar;


process_chunk = function() {
    alert("we are after chunk");
    var arrayChunk = myArray.slice(doneVar*chunkLength, (doneVar + 1)*chunkLength); 
    //alert("we are in function!!");
    $.each(arrayChunk,  function(key, item){
        $myTree.jstree("uncheck_node", "#"+item);
    });

    doneVar += 1;

    if (doneVar === groupsVar) {
        interval.clearInterval();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`process_chunk` has not been assigned a value yet, when you pass it into setInterval. Move the line:

```
var interval = setInterval(process_chunk, 1000);
```

To right before (and right after the anonymous function is assigned to `process_chunk`):

```
doneVar += 1;
```

Or if you are looking for hoisting the function then use a function declaration rather than an expression:

```
function process_chunk() {
```

Both versions will solve your problem.

Comment: Or if the only use you have for `process_chunk` is to pass it to `setInterval()` you can pass it as an anonymous function like this: `var interval = setInterval(function() {/* body of process_chunk function*/}, 1000);` I find this to be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function before using it.

Put
`process_chunk = function() {  ... });`

Before 
`var interval = setInterval(process_chunk, 1000);`

Comment: +1 One way around declaring the function first is to define it using `function process_chunk...` instead of `var process_chunk = function...`

Comment: Right. Antoher way would be to put directly the function code as a parameter of the interval function.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using the function from the interval use this (my preferred method, your way is not wrong)

```
var doneVar= 0;
var groupsVar= 4;
var $myTree= $("#myTree");
var chunkLength = myArray.length / groupsVar;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    alert("we are after chunk");
    var arrayChunk = myArray.slice(doneVar*chunkLength, (doneVar + 1)*chunkLength); 
    //alert("we are in function!!");
    $.each(arrayChunk,  function(key, item){
         $myTree.jstree("uncheck_node", "#"+item);
    });
    doneVar += 1;

    if (doneVar === groupsVar) {
         interval.clearInterval();
    }
},1000);
```

that should do it, doing it this way and defining the function within the interval prevents many problems, like in this case you need to defined the function before you set it in an interval. Here is another version keeping your style.

```
var doneVar= 0;
var groupsVar= 4;
var $myTree= $("#myTree");
var chunkLength = myArray.length / groupsVar;

var process_chunk = function() {
     alert("we are after chunk");
     var arrayChunk = myArray.slice(doneVar*chunkLength, (doneVar + 1)*chunkLength); 
     //alert("we are in function!!");
     $.each(arrayChunk,  function(key, item){
          $myTree.jstree("uncheck_node", "#"+item);
     });
     doneVar += 1;

     if (doneVar === groupsVar) {
          interval.clearInterval();
     }
}
var interval = setInterval(process_chunk, 1000);
```

I guess one other thing I noticed just now, you use `process_chuck` and not `var process_chuck` witch can cause problems too. Fixed in second answer, not applicable in first.